# How to inherit variables from one form to the other in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a new programmer, and I wanted to ask How I pass variables from Form1 to Form2
in a Windows forms App.
I created some variables that would store the data the user put in the textboxes, to then be wrote
on a new form (like lblHelloName.Text = "Hello" + name)
It's just that I don't know how to Inherit the variables from one form to the other.

```
private void btnCreateTomb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string NomeMorto = tbDeadName.Text;
        string CognomeMorto = tbDeadSurname.Text;
        int EtaMorto = Convert.ToInt32(cbDeadAge.SelectedItem);
        string NomePadre = tbFatherName.Text;
        string NomeMadre = tbMotherName.Text;
        string NomiAmici = rbFriendsNames.Text;
        string Eredita = Convert.ToString(cbHeritage.SelectedItem);
        string GenereDefunto = Convert.ToString(cbDeadGender.SelectedItem);
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        
    }
```

these are the variables I created to be shown as text in form 2, but I can't get them in form2 to be written.

I tried:
-Making public the method "btnCreateTomb_click"

```
public void btnCreateTomb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

-Inheriting the data directly from Form1

```
namespace creatombe_0._0._0
{
public partial class Form2 : Form1
```

-Creating a new "Form1"

```
        public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 f1f = new Form1();
    }
```

As said earlier, I am a beginner and maybe I have my solution under the nose, but I tried to search and the best I could find was for c++. Thank you!

Comment: Modify your form's constyructor and pass them: `Form2 f2 = new Form2(var1, var2, var3);`  There are numerous examples here for other ways . Note that this is *passing* variables not *inheriting* as the title asks

Comment: Thanks, This is what I needed! I'll edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Inherit variable from Form1 to Form2 but you can pass this variables by Constructor of form to next form then capture them, so on your btnclick

```
private void btnCreateTomb_Click(object sender, 
EventArgs e)
{
    string NomeMorto = tbDeadName.Text;
    string CognomeMorto = tbDeadSurname.Text;
    int EtaMorto = Convert.ToInt32(cbDeadAge.SelectedItem);
    string NomePadre = tbFatherName.Text;
    string NomeMadre = tbMotherName.Text;
    string NomiAmici = rbFriendsNames.Text;
    string Eredita = 
    Convert.ToString(cbHeritage.SelectedItem);
    string GenereDefunto = 
    Convert.ToString(cbDeadGender.SelectedItem);
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(NomeMorto);
    f2.ShowDialog();
}

//In form2 u doing this 
public string name;
//this is ctor
public Form2(string name)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.name=name
}
public string sayhello(string name)
{
 return "Hello"+ name;
}
```